# Pass post to another QA stackexchange

Tags: support, migration

In a case I published a post in SO and on second thought I think it more belong to Math .

How could I pass the post another QA ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Click the "flag" link under your post.

  ---

  [image]
- You will see a popup appear.
- There will be a text box in the center of the popup.
- Type a message that says something like "I would like this question to be moved to math.stackexchange.com" and explain why.

  ---

  [image]
- Click "Flag Question" in the bottom right corner.